# Get items from input list that do not exist in the database using EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to get items from input list that do not exist in the database table.

I pass a list of `IDs`, then I want to return those `IDs` that do not exist in my table.

This is what I have for now:

```
var input = new List<string>() // list of Ids, for example count of 10

var itemsThatExistInDb = await DbContext.Set<Data>() // in table exist 100k+ records,
        .AsQueryable()                               // can't use simple !Contains()
        .Where(x => input.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .ToListAsync();

var itemsThatNotExistInDb = input.Except(itemsThatExistInDb).ToList();
```

How to write a query in EF Core 2.1 to get items from my input list that do not exist in my database without using linq extensions like `Except()`? If it's possible, I want to get those `Ids` straight from my database query to `DbContext`

Comment: What is `input`? An array or list of some sort?

Comment: Its list of `Ids`. Id in my table is string

Comment: I cant use simple `!input.Contains(x.Id)` because i will fetch whole table to the memory (for example if i want to check 10 ids from input and when i had in table 100k records from !contains() i will get rest of 99990 records)

Comment: Can you write raw sql query? If yes then do a left join on input list and your db table with input list being on the left. Return those input ids which have NULL for the right side.

Comment: in `T-SQL` i could make temporary table and join it to my `Data`, is it possible in simple way in `linq` to EF?

Comment: If I am not wrong then you will get zero `Ids` in `itemsThatNotExist ` list. Because in EF query you are getting all ids which are present in input list and then you are trying `Except`.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar exactly. I want to reverse it and get ids from my `input` that not exist in database

Comment: If you check values in `itemsThatExist ` list and in `input`, all are equal

Comment: @michasaucer With LINQ left join would be comparatively more expensive or slower I think. Better if you could do it in rae sql.

Comment: I know it is pretty easy in stored procedure but i need to use linq and EF

Comment: You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#left-join).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query it like this:

```
var input = new List<string>() // list of Ids

       List<string> itemsThatExist = new List<string>();

       var itemsThatNotExist  = await DbContext.Set<Data>()
                .AsQueryable()
                .ToDictionaryAsync(_ => _.ID, _ => _);

        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            if(AllItems.ContainsKey(item)){
                itemsThatExist.Add(item);
                itemsThatNotExist.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It will work really slow. Look into my comments under original post. We cant use `!Contains()` because it can download whole table to memory (u have table with 100k records and input list have 10 records)

Comment: In total you have to download the whole table => AllItems = ItemsThatExist + ItemsThatNotExist. So Query all Items as a Dictionary and then iterate over the Dict and and add it to itemsThatExist  and itemsThatNotExist .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `!contain` you can use logical method as below:

datatTable is the content of your table.

```
List<string> fullList = new List<string>() { "3", "1", "2" }; //or any dynamic list content or class list based on requirement.
List<string> itemsThatNotExistInDb = new List<string>(); //New container list same as fullList
            foreach (var item in fullList)
            {
                var isRemoved = dataTable.RemoveAll(a => a.Id == item) == 1 ? true : false;
                if (isRemoved)
                {
                    itemsThatNotExistInDb.Add(item);
                }
            }
```